# ng build in Angular not loading

Tags: angular, production

I'm having a problem right now when building my project, the problem is that when I use the "ng build" or "npm run build" command it just says build and never finishes.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaNBX.png) and I already ran the npm install command but it doesn't work

Comment: what version of angular are you using?